# Problem in theme installing?

Tags: themes, permissions

I am trying to install a downloaded theme in `.zip` format, on my Ubuntu OS when i click on upload & try to install it, it shows the error:

> Are you sure you want to do this?
>    Please try again.

I have also trying to add theme, in themes folder which is present in `var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/theme`  but i don't get the permission to paste any folder here.

Comment: you mean you cant upload files?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your server via SSH, upload the zip file to the `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/theme/ directory`, then extract it. If you have a control panel, upload and extract the theme using the control panel file manager.

Once finished, go to WordPress administration back-end and activate the theme.

If you have SSH access to your server, check the `permissions/ownership` of `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/theme/` directory.

Comment: sorry but how can i log in via ssh

Comment: What OS do you have? If Windows, you should use some SSH client such as Putty. 
Once you download Putty, start it. No setup is required - it is a standalone executable. Run it, enter your IP address, enter the SSH port, select SSH for protocol and in the SSH settings (the last item in the menu) select protocol version 2. Click 'Open'. 
Then log in using the username and respective password.

If you have Linux or MacOS then the following command should do it:

ssh root@your_server_IP -p SSH_port

Comment: hi i am using Ubuntu 16.04 OS   when i execute this command               ssh root@192.168.30.225 -p SSH_port    then it shows me message   Bad port 'SSH_port-'

Comment: You have to use the actual port number instead of 'SSH_port'. Usually it is port 22.